# django-notification changing default template

Tags: python, django, email, templates, django-notification

I'm attempting use django-notification to send an email to the admin every time a user modifies, creates or deletes a database entry. The issue is, while I have created the notice types and confirm they exist, when the actual email is sent, the email sent looks like this:

```
You have received the following notice from example.com:

Entry has been changed. <--- this line being the email content


To see other notices or change how you receive notifications, please go to http://example.com
```

Is there a way to remove the first and last lines of that email body? I don't know where this default template is located so I can't change it. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you install django-notification? Via pip, easy_install, apt-get, ...?

Comment: sudo pip install django-notification was the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should locate the default installation directory for `pip`. If you use Linux it should be something like `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` if you use `python2.7`. Then locate the django-notification directory and change to the templates directory. And here they are!

A good idea is to copy the application to your project directory and change it here.

I simply suggest you take a look at virtualenv which will give you more flexibility for such forks.

Comment: I located the template file I wanted to change in : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notification/templates/notification/email_body.txt. However, it's write-protected meaning any changes I make cannot be saved. Can I override this template in the admin perhaps? I tried making a changed version of the template in my template folder for the project under the same name, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: You should copy the entire app `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notification/` to your project directory, change the ownership with `sudo chown -R login directory` and then you will be able to edit whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Changing system libraries are not a good idea. You can do this from your app:

1) Put the `notification` app below your app in settings.py

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
      # ...
      'your_app',
      'notification',
      # ...
 )
```

2) Create the set of base templates in `your_app/templates/notification/` directory:

- short.txt
- notice_settings.html
- notice.html
- full.txt
- full.html
- email_subject.txt
- email_body.txt
- base.html

Comment: I did not suggest to change a system librairy but to copy a pip package to edit it — avoiding the need to recreate all the templates. Even if I understand your opinion, is it worth downgrading my answer?

Comment: You're right, sorry by that. Will undo as soon as someone accepts my edit. You can let me know when that happens.